# Android - How to make activity or layout over other apps?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show message to user. But I want to do that like MusiXMatch. I don't know what is component's name.

MusixMatch shows lyrics over the other apps till user close the app or click hide button. I can explain what I want with 2 Images.

[image: When app starts, this mini icon will show always. If user clicks on it icon will expanded to Image 2:]

[image: The app shows user to music.]

I hope that I can explain what I want.

Comment: Only voting up because of the squirrel

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use floating view
https://github.com/marshallino16/FloatingView

or standout window
https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut

Comment: It looks like floating view is more recently maintained so pick that one as a first choice

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about system window overlay. A post for that is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top)

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the [SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) permission in your AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

You can find example code [here](http://androidsrc.net/facebook-chat-like-floating-chat-heads/).

Comment: Will it work without the main activity?

Comment: This example project is missing MainActivity file